# How to store a data frame in a sql server database with to_sql?

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas

I'm writing code to store a dataframe in my sql server database. The code is as follows:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

server='my_server'
database='my_database'
driver='ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server'

database_con=f'mssql+pyodbc://@{server}/{database}?driver={driver}'

engine=create_engine(database_con)
con=engine.connect()

data = [ 'test','test1', 'tests']
df_data = pd.DataFrame(data)

df_data.to_sql('dbo.test', con, index=False)
```

However, when I run the code I get an error:

```
ProgrammingError: (pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]The specified schema name "name@email.nl" either does not exist or you do not have permission to use it. (2760) (SQLExecDirectW)')
[SQL: 
CREATE TABLE [dbo.hoi] (
    [0] VARCHAR(max) NULL
)

]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/f405)
```

Does somebody know how to solve the problem?

Cheers,
Vincent

Comment: To use the table named `test` in the schema `dbo` you may wish to use `df_data.to_sql('test', con, schema='dbo', index=False)` instead.

Comment: As to the error message it seems that when you issued your `CREATE USER` command in `my_database` you included the option `WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = [name@email.nl]` but have not yet issued a `CREATE SCHEMA [name@email.nl]` to create it.

Comment: Thank you so much, your first comment worked!